# Square brackets in HTML form arrays. Just conventional or with a meaning?

Tags: html, arrays, forms

I frequently see, in particular in the PHP world, the following writing if you want to create a FORM array.

```
<input name="MyArray[]" />
<input name="MyArray[]" />
```

with the square brackets []. Nevertheless, the submit operation just passes the same key entry twice. It appears that the [] is just conventional that maps nicely to the PHP world array, but you would obtain the same result with just the following

```
<input name="MyArray" />
<input name="MyArray" />
```

Indeed, in django I get a list of two entries, regardless of the style used.

Is this true ? Are the [] just conventional, or there's actually a real meaning into it from the HTML and HTTP key/value info ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They address a limitation of PHP, which doesn't generate an array automatically if multiple values with the same name are submitted, for example from a set of checkboxes or a multiple select. (IIRC it only returns the last value.)

Personally I've always thought it to be a pretty shoddy workaround. Even Classic ASP could cope with that without requiring client-side additions to markup. The server-side platform has no business imposing markup requirements on the client in this way.

Comment: I think it was just a design decision. I don't see it as a limitation.

Comment: It's a limitation if you take existing forms that work perfectly well with any other server-side platform and try to use them with PHP: you have to change the values of all relevant element name attributes, and woe unto you if you miss one. It's an unnecessarily leaky abstraction: the HTML shouldn't be concerned with the fact that the server uses arrays, let alone that it uses C-style array-indexing syntax.

Comment: +1 `[]` was an early design mistake and one of those that PHP hasn't got around to fixing since. A different way to access parameters when you wanted to get multiple values would have been better, but wouldn't have fitted with the original `register_globals` strategy.

Comment: you can indeed access the original values with `php://input`, if you use `$_POST`, then you will get associative arrays that can have a tree structure `MyArray[key1][key2][key3]`, if you don't want it, then don't use it, but there's really no reason to complain.

Answer (score 3):

It's just conventional.

---

The W3C [states](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set):

> Let the `form data set` be **a list of name-value-type tuples**

and for each input element, on submit:

> Append an entry to the `form data set` with name as the `name`, the value of the `field` element as the value, and `type` as the type.

The W3C does not mention the use of `[]` or uniqueness of the `name` attribute.