# Form elements naming case and duplication?

Tags: html, forms

Let say my form has 2 inputs

```
<input name="person_name" value="John" type="text" />
<input name="person_name" value="Jean" type="text" />
```

When submit the form, which "person_name" will I get? John or Jean?

And if I have

```
<input name="city" value="New York" type="text" />
<input name="City" value="New York" type="text" />
```

Will I get just "city" or "City" or both of them?

Comment: if you want both use `name="person_name[index]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get two `person_name` values (i.e. both John and Jean) sent to the server, then it is up to the server to figure out what to do about it. You can have as many elements in a form with the same name as you want; the `[]` notation is just notation that some frameworks use to pass the form's structure to the server so that the server can unpack it without extra instructions and without the programmer having to differentiate between a list with one value and a single value.

You'll also get separate `city` and `City` parameters and again, it will be up to the server code to figure out how it wants to handle that.

From the [HTML4 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#successful-controls):

> Every successful control has its control name paired with its current value as part of the submitted form data set. A successful control must be defined within a FORM element and must have a control name.

There's nothing in there about selecting only one text input from several with the same `name` attribute.

Comment: Are you saying that it's server, language, or "framework" specific? In other words, can I configure the server to not "lose" any input if the `name`s are identical? When you say frameworks, what exactly are you referencing? I've been under the assumptions in my post ever since I starting writing HTML. Any chance you can enlighten me?

Comment: @Wesley: The brackets are framework specific. HTML, CGI, and HTTP know nothing of brackets or their conventional meaning.

Comment: What are you talking about when you say "frameworks"? Example of a framework? AFAIK this has nothing to do with a framework, at least with the meaning that I am used to using for that word. Example: Rails, CakePHP, Django...

Comment: @Wesley: The framework sits between the server and your code. Rails and Django certainly fit the bill. PHP itself blurs the line a bit.

Comment: @muistooshort: However, rails is a Ruby framework while Django is a Python framework, but PHP is itself a language. Is it possible to access both values in example 1 in other languages, because I'm still not understanding the framework argument?

Comment: @Wesley: PHP blurs the line between language and framework because it was originally whipped up for a very specific purpose.

Answer (score 1):

1. Jean
2. Both, `name` attribute values are case sensitive.

If you want to receive multiple values for the same `name`, consider using `brackets[]` for it's value, which will post as an array of values. Otherwise, the last value will always overwrite the previous one.

**EDIT**: This is applicable to at least *reading* the `$_REQUEST`, `$_GET` and `$_POST` values in PHP, but [as I've learned recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406213/form-elements-naming-case-and-duplication/6406248#6406248) - this is [not applicable to all languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688599/square-brackets-in-html-form-arrays-just-conventional-or-with-a-meaning). However, if you are using PHP (as far as I know), you will need to use the bracket syntax to read the input as an array of values.

Comment: Wrong. The brackets have nothing to do with HTML forms, that is just notation.

Comment: Are you saying that the bracket syntax to receive arrays is not universal? I assume that both values are sent in example 1, but are assigned to the same index, overwriting the last value.

Comment: The bracket syntax is not universal, it is merely common notation that some frameworks use. The protocols don't know what brackets are or what they mean, they're just a couple more meaningless characters that happen to appear in a `name` attribute.

Comment: @muistooshort: What "frameworks" are you talking about? I'm don't have experience with languages other than PHP, so I assumed this was how it's done, especially since similar questions come up quite a bit here (among other places) where input is not received because of duplicate `name` values (and the answers are always the same regardless of server or language used on the server side to process the input). I don't get what this has to do with a framework, it's completely independent - the framework (if it exists) has no control over the server. Am I missing something crucial?

Comment: @Wesley: PHP is a language with a built in framework. Build yourself a simple form with `method="GET"` and the four inputs, then submit it and look at the URL. Throw in some checkboxes and multi-select elements while you're at.

Comment: I don't have experience with languages other than PHP (too), web browsers other than Firefox and IE, web servers other than Apache so I wonder if it would be applied to all cases therefore I ask this question.

Comment: @muistooshort: [I see what you mean](http://wesleymurch.com/test/form1.php?person_name=John&person_name=Jean&city=New+York&City=New+York) as far as having it appear in the URL, but the `print_r($_REQUEST)` is telling a different story.

Comment: @Wesley: That's PHP's problem, it has nothing to do with HTML, the form itself, or any of the protocols. That's just PHP playing fast and loose with the standards by layer its own notation on top.

Comment: @user433531: What I have given you is a practical answer which should apply to PHP, regardless of framework or lack thereof. I think most other folks will give the same advice. The values will be assigned to superglobal arrays (post, get, request) and indexed by name. Brackets are the accepted way to use multiple values, but I'd like to hear if there are other methods. I've have no idea how to access the "overwritten" values you would get by using the same name/index.

Comment: @muistooshort: I think I understand what you're saying, but don't see how it is relevant in a practical context. As far as I know, HTML by itself has no way to access these values, so I don't get what your point is. Are you saying that if I'm processing the form with another language, these rules do not apply, and the values can be accessed? I've never heard of that, but admit ignorance (as mentioned). Example?

Comment: Yes, if you were using a different language (or even just a different parsing library rather than the built in PHP one), you could get them all without the bracket convention. For example, [mod_perl's libapreq](http://search.cpan.org/~isaac/libapreq2-2.13/glue/perl/xsbuilder/APR/Request/Request.pod#param).

Comment: @muistooshort: Thanks for you time mu, I learned something valuable. @user433531: Sorry to "take over" your post, but I hope you've learned something as well!

Comment: I appreciate this discussion a lot, thanks both of you guys for your great help :D

Comment: @Wesley: No worries. If you're ever in Whistler I'll buy you a beer (a real Canadian one) and we can argue about something else :)