# What happens to two form inputs with the same name?

Tags: forms

What is the posted value of input1 if somebody submits this form?

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="input1" type="int">
    <input name="input1" type="int">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form elements naming case and duplication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406213/form-elements-naming-case-and-duplication)

Comment: Just FYI: There is no `type="int"`, it's `type="number"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the "parser" that your plataform* use. For example, in django you get a list of both values. In PHP you only get once (the last one).

The best way is to try it!

**EDIT:**

Something to understand it a little bit more. Check it out:

http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/guide/request/

It's from the Tipify (a python framework)docs.

**Note:**
Plataform might not be the best "word" to use, but it really depends in what type of programming language you use. Also the web server, some kind of middlewere, frameworks, etc.