# My JSON Array object doesn't arrive to PHP correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I've been running to a wall several days with a problem with my AJAX form. I serialize my form with [serializeObject](https://github.com/hongymagic/jQuery.serializeObject) and that seems to be working well, but I keep having problems with an array of checkboxes that seems to not be "going through".

My form:

```
<span class="checkbox">
<span class="first">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="extra-services[]" value="logodesign">
        <span>Logo design</span>
    </label>
</span>
<span>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="extra-services[]" value="photosession">
        <span>Photo session</span>
    </label>
</span>
<span>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="extra-services[]" value="coverimage">
        <span>Facebook cover image design</span>
    </label>
</span>
<span>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="extra-services[]" value="businesscarddesign">
        <span>Business cards</span>
    </label>
</span>
<span class="last">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="extra-services[]" value="postwriting">
        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    </label>
</span>
```

The serialized object:

```
company-address: ""
company-email: ""
company-name: ""
company-rep-email: ""
company-rep-name: ""
company-rep-phone: ""
domain-existing: ""
domain-owner: ""
domain-owner-id: ""
extra-services[]: Array[3]
0: "logodesign"
1: "photosession"
2: "coverimage"
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
pack: "standard"
paying: "Aasta kaupa"
promocode: ""
```

As you can see, the extra-services is correctly serialized to an array.

When I then receive the form object in PHP and echo it back for testing, try to echo it back as a whole, I see that the extra-services array is not being treated as an array anymore and is broken:

```
extra-services[: "coverimage"
```

"coverimage" is the last item from the actual array...

Comment: why not use `$("form").serialize()` ?

Comment: And why are you using brackets ("[]") in your variable names? Just curious.

Comment: @mrunion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688599/square-brackets-in-html-form-arrays-just-conventional-or-with-a-meaning

Comment: Cool. Thanks! I've wrote PHP for a great many years and never ran across needing this, so thanks for the info.